# How do I download a certificate from an endpoint with .Net?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

We have a public certificate on our web service but I need to download the certificate from within my client code. I have looked at WebClient and HttpClient but I don't see where the downloaded certificate would be at in the response.

Can someone guide me in the correct location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.110).aspx